# Best JSON library for .NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net, json

I'm looking forward to write a ASP.NET website which is using JSON to interact with a webservice. JSON.org gives me some choices, but I don't know which is the best, and is there some good libraries that not listed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hands down [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx). Simply the best, most flexible, most extensible, easy to use JSON library for .NET.